# SharePoint List End Date

Tags: list

I have a SharePoint list with Items. for example I know the start date of the item using "Created" field similarly I want to know the end date of the item. So do we have any field in SharePoint List which tells us end date of that item ?

Comment: What defines end? As with created, and end date would simply be a piece of metadata (column, field, etc). The difference being that created is by default on all sharepoint content types and created has a static definition, while no item has an end, unless deleted, but then the item is done and deleted must be logged elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by the End Date you are looking for 
 - the Timespan between Now and when the item has been Created  - create a Calculated column using Today token and Created
 - Timespan between moment of creation (Created field) and time when last changed, use again a calculated column using the Modified field.

See here for calculated columns - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Anything else it will be related to what exactly "end date" would actually mean to you (e.g Task content types have Start Date and Due Date, etc.)

Comment: yes that's what I need. "Created" implies Start Time and "Modified" implies End time of an item in a list.Thank You Marius.